# document.evalute not working on RSS feeds page

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpath, rss, firefox-addon

I'm in Firefox and am using the standard 'document.evaluate' method that has been working for everything else so far. But on RSS feeds pages like this:

http://msutoday.msu.edu/rss/all/

even a simple query is not working for me. When I open this page in Firefox, Open the Scratchpad from Developer Tools (Shift+F4) and try

```
var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate("//div[@id='feedContent']", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
alert(nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength);
```

It gives 0 as a result while I know there is a div element with id 'feedContent'. I can confirm this from the HTML Inspector and also by trying just below the above code lines in the same Scratchpad window:

```
alert(document.getElementById('feedContent'));
```

Why would document.evaluate fail here and how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a firefox extension? Or within a website?

Comment: @Noitidart : This is for a Firefox extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand it yet, but apparently, your JS is *not* evaluated against the source document of that page, which would be an RSS feed.

Instead, the browser encapsulates the feed in an XHTML wrapper (a feed handler), where the outermost element carries a *default namespace*. This `div` element therefore is in a namespace. If you change your expression to something more general, not directly involving element names:

```
var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate("//*[@id='feedContent']", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
```

or

```
var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate("//*[local-name() = 'div' and @id='feedContent']", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );

alert(nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength);
```

the Scratchpad will return `1`.

Comment: Thanks! But do you think it's a bug? Because if it had a different tag name, document.getElementsByTagName('div'); shouldn't have returned an element with id 'feedContent'.

Comment: @PiyushSoni No, it's definitely not a bug. There _is_ a `div` element with that ID, it's just that it's in a namespace, but `document.getElementsByTagName()` does not care about namespaces.